Is there any "minimalist" GVim (or any GUI-based Vim) distribution for Windows?
I'm currently working on a simple WPF (Windows) application that employs GVim as an embedded text editor.
The application is supposed to embed GVim into itself as follows (although it's mostly irrelevant to the question):

It creates a blank Win32 window within an HwndHost (HwndHost is a WPF control that lets you host any Win32 window inside it).
It launches GVim while passing the abovementioned Win32 window handle through the --windowid command line option (this way GVim launches itself attached to the Win32 window).

While trying to make it work, I noticed that the official Vim/GVim distribution is kinda bloated.
The official Vim 9.1 distribution (https://github.com/vim/vim-win32-installer/releases/download/v9.1.0/gvim_9.1.0_x64_signed.zip) contains 2,507 files (58.0MB in total), and it takes roughly 1min to extract (using the standard Windows 11 Zip extractor), which more than doubles the extraction time of my application when bundled.
I noticed that even after I deleted all the folders in the extracted folder (just 58 top-level files remaining, 13.3MB in total size) GVim is still able to launch, even though some error dialogs show up and the menu bar and the tool bar are visibly missing. I tried to open some text file and typed in some standard commands as well, most of which seemed to work fine (the only thing I noticed missing was the file browser, which I could do without).
This experience made me wonder if there is any Vim(GVim) distribution that takes a lightweight/minimalistic approach. Of course it is sensible to argue that Vim is kinda for power users and power users don't like the editor being stripped down, but 2,507 files and 58MB still feels too big to be bundled with a 400KB exe file.
Does anyone happen to know of any lightweight/minimalistic Vim(GVim) distribution that works on Windows and is actively maintained? NeoVim-based ones are fine, but as far as I could see, none of them seem to support the abovementioned approach to embed the editor into another Windows application.
Thanks in advance.

GVim can run without its runtime, which is where most of the weight is, but a) that makes it very barebones because lots of functionalities depend on that runtime, including everything filetype-related, and your users will certainly be pissed off by that broken "GVim", b) the binary itself already weights more than 2mb anyway, which is way more than your own application. Overall, I don't think this is a good idea. Are there not native text editing widget in WIN32? Something like NSTextView on Macs?

Thank you for the quick reply, actually the application is for a certain workflow that is currently done using Vim. The current version of the application uses a native WPF control for text editing but people are not happy with it because most of the thing they used to do within a matter of keystrokes it can't, which is why I'm eyeing embedded Vim to enable a more familiar experience to users. And I'm pretty sure that most of the prospective users don't use many advanced features of Vim (most people don't even have any plugin installed) which is why I think a stripped-down Vim could suffice.

Debian maintainers took the other road and offer a variety of stripped down Vims starting from vim-tiny. You could take a look there for inspiration. Note that this site and SO face a constant influx of "why can't my Vim do X?" questions from users who have only the minimal version installed and don't realize it. It's 2024 and 58 MBs is the size of an instant message you send from your phone.
